# OpenID nickname on Blogger showing up as "openid" for delegate page

Tags: blogger, openid

I have my site set up so I can log in using it as my openID. The log in works, however I have a problem on Blogger. My name shows up as "openid" instead of "radicalpi". The link to the profile is correct (radicalpi.myopenid.com), just not the nickname. If I use radicalpi.myopenid.com in place of my domain, the nickname shows up correctly. Is this a bug with Blogger, or is there something I should change on my end to make it function properly.

I have the following in the head section of my site's root:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server">
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://radicalpi.myopenid.com">
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server">
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://radicalpi.myopenid.com">
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://www.myopenid.com/xrds?username=radicalpi.myopenid.com">
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but a possible workaround: if you have a domain (and not a subdomain from blogger), you can create a subdomain (eg. `id.mydomain.com`) and CNAME it to MyOpenID instead of using the HTML tags. See [here](https://www.myopenid.com/product_domains).

Comment: Setting up a subdomain and setting a CNAME for it worked. As you said, not quite a solution, but it does fix the problem.